# JQuery Selector for selecting Table on bases of clicked TR

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I have scenario like below:

```
<table class="gridTable" myattr="true">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>  


<table class="gridTable" myattr="false">
<tr>
  <td>CT</td>
  <td>DK</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>RT</td>
  <td>VD</td>
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, here both table has same class "gridTable".

I have written clicked event on TR of that class like below

```
jQuery(".gridTable > tbody > tr").click(function( evehappnedOn ){ ... });
```

I have to write jQuery selector which will select only that table from which TR clicked is triggered.

Basically in above scenario,
if suppose i clicked on "Smith" so it will check its parent TR then Its Table and give me its attribute "myattr" which is either "true" OR "false".

NOTE : I cant assign unique IDs to tables as I have to keep the JS script generic.

Comment: Use `.closest('table')` to target the TABLE. That's said, you should use valid attributes as `data-myattr`

Comment: if you use `$(this)`, it will refer to the same tr. And you can handle the event as `$(".gridTable tr").click(function( evehappnedOn ){ //Here $(this) refers to the current tr clicked ... });`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent:: Yes $(this) will refer to same TR but how to get "myattr" attribute value of its parent table.

Comment: @A.Wolff :  Sorry i dint get you. can you please write down some sample code?

Comment: @ChetanT. you can do it like `$(this).closest('table').attr('myattr');` Try to change `myattr` to `data-myattr` and access it as `$(this).closest('table').attr('data-myattr');`

Comment: For the latter (`data-myattr`) I suppose you could also do `$(this).closest('table').data('myattr');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it like:

```
$(".gridTable tr").click(function( evehappnedOn ){

   var attr = $(this).closest('table').attr('myattr'); 
   ... 

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

That would give you the attr value

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/QZEw5/

```
$('.gridTable').on('click', 'td', function(e){
    var myattr = $(e.delegateTarget).attr('myattr');
});
```

Comment: This is the better solution, because you're no searching the DOM tree and also the event listeners are less in count